# Qt layouts, difference between passing and not passing QWidget as parent

Tags: c++, qt

I have created a simple `QHBoxLayout` (horizontal) that is pushed to the bottom of the `QVBoxLayout` (Vertical)  and it contains two buttons. See code:

```
QWidget* create_ver_and_horizontal_box() {
    QWidget* temp = new QWidget();

    // Add buttons to the horizontal box
    QHBoxLayout* hbox = new QHBoxLayout();

    QPushButton *ok = new QPushButton("OK");
    QPushButton *cancel = new QPushButton("Cancel");

    hbox->addWidget(ok);
    hbox->addWidget(cancel);

    // Create a vertical box and add the horizontal box to 
    // the end of it
    QVBoxLayout* vbox = new QVBoxLayout();   
    vbox->addStretch(1);
    vbox->addLayout(hbox);

    // set the layout and return
    temp->setLayout(vbox);
    return temp;
}
```

and the resulting UI is the following.
[image]

But when I add the QWidget `temp` to be the parent of the QHBoxLayout, like so:

```
    // Add buttons to the horizontal box
    QHBoxLayout* hbox = new QHBoxLayout(temp);
```

This is what I get:
[image]

I want to understand what is going on here. And in which cases I want the QWidget to be the parent of a layout or any other QWidget(s) and in which cases I don't the containing QWidget to be the parent of the containing QWidgets. For example, I could've added temp to be the parent of the two Push buttons but I didn't. What is the implication of not adding vs adding.

Thanks,

Comment: Qt layout will manage parents for you and they will be set/updated properly by calling `addWidget()/addLayout()`. In your second case the created object `vbox` is not used anywhere (only the hbox) and therefore the buttons are placed in horizontal layout. The vertical centering is default behaviour of the `QHBoxLayout`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
QHBoxLayout* hbox = new QHBoxLayout(temp);
```

is equivalent to

```
QHBoxLayout* hbox = new QHBoxLayout();
temp->setLayout(hbox);
```

I.e. you are making the horizontal layout responsible for `temp`.

The call to `setLayout(vbox)` should have generated a runtime warning message, that `temp` already has a layout, hinting at that.

Since you want the vertical layout to be responsible for that widget, either keep the `temp->setLayout(vbox)` or pass  `temp` to the constructor of `QVBoxLayout`.

Comment: that makes a lot of sense, thank you for clearing that up.